# Ember-Validations: Installation

Tags: validation, ember.js, ember-cli

I have an Ember-CLI application that is very form heavy.

I started using **[Ember Forms](http://ember-addons.github.io/ember-forms/#/overview)** to help with layout and templating, which is nice and seems to be working fine.

Apparently for validation, it requires **[Dockyard's Ember-Validation](https://github.com/dockyard/ember-validations)** as well... This particular dependency seems to be installed differently and I am lost as how to do this.

I am used to using something simple like `bower install ...` and then just adding the dependency in `brocfile`, but in this case, Dockyard provides a huge list of builds to choose from and I have no idea which one to use?

Does anyone have experience installing ember-validation in an ember-cli project and getting to play nicely with ember-forms?  Or perhaps it is actually more simple than I think, and I am just getting thrown off by all the builds to choose from?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To install it you can add manually the url to the build in `bower.json`

```
"ember-validations": "http://builds.dockyard.com.s3.amazonaws.com/ember-validations/ember-validations-latest.js",
```

And after that run `bower install` it should work fine.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Wow this helps a lot thanks! I got the dependency installed.  I will see if I can get it integrated now.

Comment: when I try run this I get this error: **bower ember-data.model-fragments#0.2.1          ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/lytics/ember-data.model-fragments.git", exit code of #128**

Comment: @SuperUberDuper you are trying to install `ember-validations`? In the error I see you have problem with different package `ember-data.model-fragments`

Comment: what is stopping dockyards from adding ember-validations to bower?

Comment: @kushdilip Based on this issue https://github.com/dockyard/ember-validations/issues/130 they don't like the `dist` folder I guess. But now if you use `ember-cli` you can install it through npm as shown in their docs.